# When i am trying to run the sample corda application in my ubuntu system its too much hanging

Tags: corda

I installed all prerequisites as mentioned for ubuntu machine
(JDK-8, intellij IDEA, git).
I clone the sample code from the git. It's running but system got struct too much.
My system configurations are operating system : ubuntu 16.04, RAM :4Gb , Hard Disk:500 Gb. Is there any alternative solution for this problem any one can help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? When does it get stuck? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is run all the nodes in your local with 4Gig of ram. which is making your machine hang, It can hard for the OS to accommodate each node, provided with limited memory.

Comment: Tanks for the reply, then what is the solution for this issue. You mean i need to run the different nodes in different machines. If that is the case how to run different nodes in different machines.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered at: [Cordapp tutorial crashing in a Fedora VirtualBox Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242579/cordapp-tutorial-crashing-in-a-fedora-virtualbox-machine)

For similar reason: your RAM is too small to handle multiple nodes.

According to our documentation, Corda has a suggested minimal requirement of 1GB of Heap and 2-3GB of Host RAM per node. https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/sizing-and-performance.html#sizing