# Cordapp tutorial crashing in a Fedora VirtualBox Machine

Tags: corda

I have downloaded the Cordapp example provided in the Corda website. I follow all the steps (to run it from the console) in 
https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html

without any problem until "Running the example CorDapp". Here i get to errors one way or another.

First, when running
workflows-kotlin/build/nodes/runnodes

one or more of the nodes would not start. I was using a virtual machine with 2 cores and 4GB of RAM. Eventually, i noticed it seemed to be an issue with the RAM, so i changed the VM condig to 4 cpus and 10 GB of RAM.

Now, i can run 
workflows-kotlin/build/nodes/runnodes

and get all 4 nodes working but, as soon as I run the following instruction
/gradlew runPartyXServer 
Where X=[A,B,C] for each of the possible nodes, after 20-30 seconds as much, the machine repently slows down and aborts.

The VM has Fedora 30, 4 cores and 10GB of RAM. It is empty except for what i downloaded for the tutorial. I cannot believe those are not enough resources to run the tutorial, Am i wrong? Do i need more? may it be another thing?

Any help is welcome.

== Solved ==

The issue were the resources. I jumped to 8 cores and 32GB and it ran. I will try at some point with 16GB. In any case, the problem, from my point of view, is that having those large hardware requirements, the tutorial should include a section describing the minimum setup needed to run it.

Comment: Are there any errors generated. Detailed logs are present in logs subdirectory.

Comment: Actually, some logs are not even there. Apparently, as the VM crashes either it crhashes before the log is updated or the state is lost.

Answer (score 0):

From the given information, I believe you had ran into a Memory issue.

According to our documentation, Corda has a suggested minimal requirement of 1GB of Heap and 2-3GB of Host RAM per node. 
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/sizing-and-performance.html#sizing

I would suggest either reduce the number of nodes hosted on a single machine or expand your RAM size of the VM